# Extract displayed text from any kind of software

Tags: .net, windows, text-extraction

Is there any way to scan or rather extract the displayed text of any software or application running in Windows, so it can be save and used later without explicit knowledge of the kind of software running (also including any service of Windows itself, for example the Desktop or Windows Explorer)?

So for example, you could write a software that runs in the background of Windows, which can find any word or text that is currently displayed on the screen no matter what software is currently focused.

I already thought of looking through the .NET Library classes, because I could remember trying out the Windows Speech Recognition, which was able to select items/buttons/etc. based on their displayed name, but I haven't been lucky yet.

Comment: System.Windows.Automation namespace.

Answer (score 0):

[Word web](http://wordweb.info/free/) has this kind of feature. Don't know how the do it. On right clicking anywhere on the screen it tries to find the word in dictionary.